# Browsers in Docker container (via Selenium Webriver) have very slow internet

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid, docker-network

On my local machine, the tests run correctly, and are over within a couple seconds (The tests are accessing a demo flight booking site, and then duckduckgo/google).

I set up a Grid on a Docker network using the below compose file. Each grid node is it's own container. I've confirmed the grid is up and running successfully.

```
version: '3'
services:
  hub: 
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome: 
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
    shm_size: 4gb
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
    ports:
      - '7777:5900'
  firefox: 
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug:latest
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
    ports:
      - '8777:5900'
```

When I run the test connected to the grid containers, the browser opens (I am viewing it by a VNC viewer). After that, it's clear that something is wrong. The initial "registration" page of the sample site loads, but takes up to 30 seconds. After that first page is filled out, and "next" is clicked, the next page in the workflow does not load. I tried different memory settings, but the browser itself seems very responsive. It's just the network that is slow.

[image: page load failure]

In fact, that demo page, although slow, is the *only* thing I can get to load in the container's browser. Google, DuckduckGo, etc spin until they fail. I can stop the Selenium tests and try to use the browser manually, and can't access anything except the demo page (https://vins-udemy.s3.amazonaws.com/docker/docker-book-flight.html).

Since the tests work fine locally, I believe the issue is not with Selenium. Rather, the containers themselves have unusably slow internet. They *do* have some connection, as I can access that very simple form page. But anything beyond that will not load.

**SO:** Is there some network setting I am missing that causes my containers to be incredibly slow accessing the internet?

**And:** is there an easier way to debug the network speed of my containers to the internet? Every search result I've seen has to do with some other case like speed between host/container.

Comment: CAN YOU TRY DOCKER RUN CONTAINENER NAME --dns 8.8.8.8

Comment: @dsider88, I am also facing the similar issue like y script execution time is increased while executing on docker containers via selenium grid. Also getting many failures like element not found.

So did you find any solution ?

Comment: Any joy with this? Seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: @Rossimac are you on a corporate proxy? That was the problem for me. Opened a ticket with the firewall team, I am not exactly sure what they did to fix it.

Prior to getting this official Selenium image fixed, I was able to work around the issue by using a customized AmazonLinux2 image instead, and manually installing Selenium, a desktop environment, and all dependencies